# Job to send email with quartz, unable to Session.getInstance

Tags: java, cron, jakarta-mail, quartz

i am new to quartz and javamail but i need to send email by batch job. I tried to
1. send email with single java class: success
2. run job with quarts (only println): success
3. run job with quarts (to send email): failed

this is my job class:

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.activation.*;
import org.quartz.*;


public class EmailJob implements Job {

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        try {
            EmailSender es = new EmailSender();
            es.sendBillingEmail();

            System.out.println("Job Email Runnning");
            final String username = "abcde@mydomain.com";
            final String password = "xxxxxxxxxx";

            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.mydomain.com");//smtp.gmail.com
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");//587

            Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
                    new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                }
            });
            System.out.println("Job Email Running 2");
            // Sending email
            try {

                Message message = new MimeMessage(session);

                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("abcde@mydomain.com"));
                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("myemail@gmail.com"));
                message.setSubject("Test Email");
                String body = "Dear Bapak Recipients"
                        + "<br>Just test email";

                message.setContent(body, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
                Transport.send(message);

                System.out.println("Done");

            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

the result:

```
Job Email Running (i got this message in console)
Job Email Running 2 (i code this but didnt see in console, 
         my suspect theres an error when creating session)
```

quartz.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<job-scheduling-data
    xmlns="http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/JobSchedulingData"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/JobSchedulingData http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/job_scheduling_data_1_8.xsd"
    version="1.8">  
    <pre-processing-commands>
        <delete-jobs-in-group>*</delete-jobs-in-group>  <!-- clear all jobs in scheduler -->
        <delete-triggers-in-group>*</delete-triggers-in-group> <!-- clear all triggers in scheduler -->
    </pre-processing-commands>
    <processing-directives>
        <overwrite-existing-data>true</overwrite-existing-data>
        <ignore-duplicates>false</ignore-duplicates>
    </processing-directives>
    <schedule>
        <job>
            <name>EmailJob</name>
            <job-class>jobs.EmailJob</job-class>
        </job>
        <trigger>
            <cron>
                <name>EveryWorkDay</name>
                <job-name>EmailJob</job-name>     
                <cron-expression>0 0/2 * 1/1 * ? *</cron-expression><!-- 0 0 20 ? * MON-FRI * -->
            </cron>
        </trigger>
    </schedule>
</job-scheduling-data>
```

quartz.properties

```
# Generic configuration - probably not needed, most of this is just the defaults
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = MyScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = 1
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.export = false
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.proxy = false
org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 20
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore

# Configure it to look in the quartz.xml for the job schedules
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.class = org.quartz.plugins.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.fileNames = quartz.xml
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.failOnFileNotFound = true
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.scanInterval = 120
```

there is no error in console. i have no idea where is the mistake. Need help from u guys.

Comment: Are you getting an exception?  What does the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) show?  Note that you can simplify your code by fixing the [common JavaMail mistakes](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes).

Comment: Hi Bill, i didn't get an exception. I tried to take out sending email part to another class "EmailSender", but still same problem.. its always stuck when i call Session.getInstance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, it can work. I updated library to Java Mail version 1.6.0.. and its work with the same code. Hope this help to other with same problem with me. You can download it in this link:

https://github.com/javaee/javamail/releases